# PhoneGap 3, iOS7 and CDVBarcodeScanner.o

Tags: cordova, ios7, barcode, xcode5

I'm using Phonegap 3.0 and XCode 5 and am attempting to include a barcode scanner in my iOS7 app using

```
https://github.com/wildabeast/BarcodeScanner
```

which I've added to the project by downloading a zip of the project from github and installing via

```
phonegap local plugin add /dev/BarcodeScanner-master
```

but when I attempt to run from XCode 5 I'm getting

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7s:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CATransaction", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in CDVBarcodeScanner.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7s
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

The error seems to relate to the armv7s architecture, but obviously I can't turn that off as I'm building to iOS7.

Anybody managed to get this (or any other) barcode reader working with Phonegap 3 & iOS7?

Thanks,
D

Comment: For what it's worth, I can get this working in Cordova but not Phonegap. So for now, Cordova it is...

Answer (score 7):

Try to add QuartzCore framework to link with your project. Go Build Phases -> Link Binary With   Libraries and add QuartzCore.